# django reverse match problems

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to figure out why I'm having trouble with this.  Everything seems to be fine, and I have no problems with other urls reversing.  When I enter the URL manually, the page comes up fine.

This is the template tag that causes the problems:  `{% url 'schedule:calendar' %}`

Here is urls.py:

```
app_name = 'schedule'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(views.CalendarView.as_view(), login_url='/login/'), name='calendar'),
]
```

I don't think it's necessary, but my views file has only this in it:

```
class CalendarView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'schedule/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CalendarView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['template'] = 'calendar_view'
        return context
```

I don't see naming conflicts at all, yet when I put `{% url 'schedule:calendar' %}` in my template, anywhere, it throws the error, even if that is the only thing in the template page.

Here is the error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/schedule/

Django Version: 1.10.3 Python Version: 3.5.2 Installed Applications: ['footables',  'floppyforms',  'djangobower',  'custom_user',  'bootstrap3_datetime',  'widget_tweaks',  'schedule.apps.ScheduleConfig',  'customers.apps.CustomersConfig',  'employees.apps.EmployeesConfig',  'jobs.apps.JobsConfig',  'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig',  'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'rest_framework',  'mptt'] Installed Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error: In template /home/poduck/PycharmProjects/mobileautorepair/schedule/templates/schedule/index.html, error at line 0    Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []   1 : {% extends 'frontend/base.html' %}{% load staticfiles %}{% block style %}    2 :  <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css' %}'/>{% endblock %}    3 : {% block title %}Schedule{% endblock %}    4 : {% block body %}    5 :    <div class="container">    6 :         <div id="calendar"></div>    7 :     </div>    8 : {% endblock %}    9 : {% block script %}    10 :   <script src="{% static 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js' %}"></script>


Traceback:

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  109.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  86.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  439.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix,
*args, **kwargs)))

File "/home/poduck/virtualpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /schedule/ Exception Value: Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Can you post your debug information for patterns' order (just hit the wrong url and Django will display in "debug on" it for you) ?

Comment: Share your root `urls.py`.

Comment: Like @utkbansal mentions, what is your root url conf ? Make sure you have provided the right namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you post your debug information for patterns' order (just hit the
>   wrong url and Django will display in "debug on" it for you) ? – Artem
>   Bernatskyi

Thanks to Artem Bernatskyi's comment, I figured it out.  I have an API for the data, and I had a namespace conflict in the urls.py file for that api.  It had `app_name='schedule'` in it as well.  I renamed it, and everything works fine now.

For anyone having the same problem, it might be fastest if you just do a search through all your code for the names you are trying to reverse match.  Make sure they don't appear in another urls.py file.

Thank you Artem.